# How to change color of link tag text in HTML?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

```css
.myActive{
 background:white;
 color: red;
}
.navbar > li > a:hover,
.navbar > li > a:focus{
 background: ;
 color: #333;
}
```

```html
<ul class="navbar">
    <li> <a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li> <a href="#">Categories</a></li>
    <li> <a href="#">About us</a></li>
    <li class="myActive"> <a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

I want to change color of my text in `<a>` tag so I write a class that change background of li tag but it's not changed my color text in li.

After a little research I understand that I need to add `<span>` to my text.
but I don't understand why i need do this, `<a>` and `<span>` are inline elements.

```
.navbar > li > a:hover,
.navbar > li > a:focus{
 background: white;
 color: #333;
}
```

and why pseudo class focus do the work ?

Comment: Could you provide the HTML or a jsfiddle? I don't see any reason why this wouldn't work in your current example.

Comment: What you have should work. Please post your HTML. Realize though that the CSS you have will only work if the element has focus or is being hovered. Otherwise the default color will apply.

Comment: are you working in a framework, such as Wordpress?  There may be styles further down the line which are overriding your attempts.  Try to inspect in Chrome DeBugger (F12).  Also, you could try color:#333!important; to test.  !important will override may other styles.  You may need to add specificity to your selector.

Comment: I need to make active class of current page without using <span> or else element.

Comment: try ul.navbar > li.myActive a {color:red;}

Comment: Thank you Jason Im stuck with this maybe a hour!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want change your link color:

```
.navbar > li > a{
  color: red;
}
```

not

```
.navbar > li{
  color: red;
}
```

So add CSS for the link element not the li.
You don't need span.
Focus works because you write css for the link element in focus state.

Comment: Thanks, its help me.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your HTML is like this

```
<ul>
<li><a href="http://www.thesite.net>This Site</a></li>
</ul>
```

To change the text colour of the link the css is simple

```
li a{ color: red;}
```

I would also recommend adding a hover colour:

```
li a:hover{color: blue;}
```